# How to get comma between Freemarker list

Tags: java, freemarker

I am iterating a java list in freemarker , but I want commas in between the words. 
Here's my code

```
<#list key_list[key] as value >${value?js_string}, </#list>
```

This gives me output as

```
a,b,c,d,
```

I want the output in this format:(No comma in the end)

```
a,b,c,d
```

How can I get that

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You have to include an `<#if value_has_next>,</#if>` statement.

This may help:

```
<#assign seq = ["winter", "spring", "summer", "autumn"]>
<#list seq as x>
  ${x_index + 1}. ${x}<#if x_has_next>,</#if>
</#list>
```

will output:

1. winter,
2. spring,
3. summer,
4. autumn

See this and more examples at:

http://freemarker.org/docs/ref_directive_list.html

Comment: If you freemarker version is 2.3.23 or higher, sep tag will work for you:
<#list users as user>
    ${user}<#sep>, </#sep>
</#list>

OR even shorter than that:
<#list users as user>${user}<#sep>, </#list>

Comment: Where `#sep` is not flexible enough, the recommended form is `x?has_next` instead of `x_has_next` (since 2.3.23), also there are `?is_first`, `?index`, and other loop variable built-ins (https://freemarker.apache.org/docs/ref_builtins_loop_var.html).

Answer (score 26):

If you use FreeMarker version 2.3.23 or higher, [`sep`](https://freemarker.apache.org/docs/ref_directive_list.html#ref_list_sep) tag will work for you:

```
<#list users as user>
    ${user}<#sep>, </#sep>
</#list>
```

OR even shorter than that:

```
<#list users as user>${user}<#sep>, </#list>
```

Answer (score 1):

This will give exact result

Actually you need to create a variable , then append data in it. e.g `<#assign result =""/>`

```
<#assign result =""/>
<#assign seq = ["a", "b", "c", "d"]> // test data for checking output format
<#list seq as x>  
 <#assign result = result+"${x}"/> 
 <#if x_has_next>
  <#assign result = result+","/>
 </#if>
</#list>  
${result}
```

**Result**

```
a,b,c,d
```

Comment: Since FTL 2.3.23, x_has_next has changed to x?has_next. Also, this works for hashes as well (eg hashKey?has_next).